# SwiftUI: How to trim circle in clock style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, geometry

I am making quiz app where in need to create timer that look like this image

[image: 1]

So it doesn't trim in normal way but I has to work like hands of the clock.
I've tried to use custom shapes to actually draw it by myself because I know the center point, radius and starting point. So I spent few hours on that and I give up, maybe you can tell me if there is an easier way or you know why my code isn't working as supposed to.

Here is my custom Shape:

```
struct ClockShape: Shape {
    var trim: Double
    
    func properPoint(_ rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        let r: CGFloat = 2 //rect.height/2
        let s: CGFloat = 2 //rect.midX
        let tempLength: CGFloat = sqrt(abs(2*pow(r, 2) - (4 * r * cos(360 * trim))))
        let length = sqrt(abs(tempLength))
        let a: CGFloat = ((pow(r, 2) - sqrt(abs(length))) / (-2 * s)) - s
        let b: CGFloat = sqrt(abs(sqrt(abs(length)) - pow((a - s), 2)))
        
        return CGPoint(x: a, y: b)
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let point = properPoint(rect)
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        
        return path
    }
}
```

Here is a ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ClockShape(trim: 0.5)
                .fill(Color.accentColor)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
        }
    }
}
```

It should draw a circle trimmed by a value of 'trim' (e.g 0.5 -> 50%)

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Running this in Xcode it just draws a black triangle. Please update your code to show a _minimal_ example that reproduces the issue; ideally a `struct ContentView` that someone can paste into Xcode and run. Please take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Yes because this code isn't working for some reason, and it should draw a trimmed circle with the value of trim (0.5 - half circle etc.), it is triangle right now because instead of arc I draw a line but it isn't the most important thing right now because the only thing I need right now is functionality that will crop a circle (or draw) in style of a clock hands like on an image above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating the problem. To draw a trimmed circle, use `Circle()` and `.trim`. Here's an example that scales to fit its frame, with animation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            clock(value)
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            
            Slider(value: $value, in: 0...10)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
    func clock(_ value: Double) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.pink.opacity(0.3))
                Circle()
                    .inset(by: proxy.size.width / 4)
                    .trim(from: 0, to: value /  10)
                    .stroke(.pink.opacity(0.6), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: proxy.size.width / 2))
                    .rotationEffect(.radians(-.pi/2))
                    .animation(.linear, value: value)
                Text("\(Int(value))")
                    .font(Font.system(size: proxy.size.width / 2))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]